# Dynamic Feature Module not getting installed

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-delivery

I am adding an on demand dynamic feature module on my app, but I am having a problem.

When I install that feature module

```
val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
    .addModule("ondemandfeature")
    .build()
splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
```

The following log is printed

```
12:54:42.301/? I/PlayCore: UID: [11113]  PID: [30056] SplitInstallService : startInstall([ondemandfeature],[])
12:54:42.807/? I/Finsky: [2] mvr.a(112): Installer: Request install. package=com.package.my, version=16081, mods=[ondemandfeature], priority=2, reason=SplitInstallService
12:54:43.239/? I/Finsky: [2] myc.a(325): IT: Required downloads: [..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi, ..split.ondemandfeature, ..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt]
12:54:43.263/? I/Finsky: [2] mpw.a(3): Downloading full file for com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi)
12:54:43.282/? I/Finsky: [2] mxo.a(2): IT: Send Resource Request for com.package.my downloadid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi).
12:54:43.287/? I/Finsky: [2] mxc.a(8): IT: Sent download request for com.package.my, adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi, isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32
12:54:43.379/? D/DownloadManager: [6235] Starting {ondemandfeature feature for MyAppName} by {10058:com.android.vending}
12:54:44.296/? I/Finsky: [2] myc.a(174): IT: Prepare to copy com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32) from content://downloads/my_downloads/6235 (expect 17096 bytes, isCompressed: false)
12:54:44.322/? I/Finsky: [87461] dxz.doInBackground(18): com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi) (17096 bytes) copied successfully in 0 ms
12:54:44.329/? I/Finsky: [2] mxh.a(5): IT: Successfully copied APK to update com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.xxhdpi , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32)
12:54:44.342/? I/Finsky: [2] mpw.a(3): Downloading full file for com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature)
12:54:44.346/? I/Finsky: [2] mxo.a(2): IT: Send Resource Request for com.package.my downloadid: ..split.ondemandfeature).
12:54:44.350/? I/Finsky: [2] mxc.a(8): IT: Sent download request for com.package.my, adid: ..split.ondemandfeature, isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32
12:54:44.382/? D/DownloadManager: [6236] Starting {ondemandfeature feature for MyAppName} by {10058:com.android.vending}
12:54:44.920/? I/Finsky: [2] myc.a(174): IT: Prepare to copy com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32) from content://downloads/my_downloads/6236 (expect 168472 bytes, isCompressed: false)
12:54:44.934/? I/Finsky: [87462] dxz.doInBackground(18): com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature) (168472 bytes) copied successfully in 2 ms
12:54:44.938/? I/Finsky: [2] mxh.a(5): IT: Successfully copied APK to update com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32)
12:54:44.949/? I/Finsky: [2] mpw.a(3): Downloading full file for com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt)
12:54:44.953/? I/Finsky: [2] mxo.a(2): IT: Send Resource Request for com.package.my downloadid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt).
12:54:44.957/? I/Finsky: [2] mxc.a(8): IT: Sent download request for com.package.my, adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt, isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32
12:54:44.996/? D/DownloadManager: [6237] Starting {ondemandfeature feature for MyAppName} by {10058:com.android.vending}
12:54:45.425/? I/Finsky: [2] myc.a(174): IT: Prepare to copy com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32) from content://downloads/my_downloads/6237 (expect 12626 bytes, isCompressed: false)
12:54:45.439/? I/Finsky: [87461] dxz.doInBackground(18): com.package.my (..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt) (12626 bytes) copied successfully in 3 ms
12:54:45.450/? I/Finsky: [2] mxh.a(5): IT: Successfully copied APK to update com.package.my (adid: ..split.ondemandfeature.config.pt , isid: 21FGah5gQD6I6P4uDfGY32)
```

Which makes me believe that the dynamic feature module gets successfullt installed. But when I try to check the installed modules:

```
splitInstallManager.installedModules
```

It returns an empty list.

Is there something I am missing?

---

Addional info:

Here is the log of a `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener`:

```
// begin
PENDING (printed 4x)
DOWNLOADING (printed 14x)
INSTALLING (printed 1x)
DOWNLOADED (printed 1x)
// end
```

I also perceived that right after the `INSTALLING` log, the following one is printed:

```
I/Finsky: [2] dyv.<init>(17): com.package.my is installed but certificate mismatch
```

What does it mean?

---

Additional info 2:

On a Pixel 3XL (Android 10) device, the on demand dynamic feature module is successfully downloaded and installed.

But, on a Motorola G5 (Android 8.1) device, the on demand dynamic feature module is only downloaded, but never installed.

---

Additional info 3:

For some reason, the download and installation is working only on Android 10 devices, but I don't know why.

---

*To test that feature, I am using the **internal app sharing tool**, where I can upload the app bundle*.

Comment: same here! did you found any solution?

Comment: Hi, @pumnao. Thanks for the reminding. Indeed I did :tada:. Please, take a look at the answer that I posted ^^.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that I was passing through those problems due to a misconfiguration in my project.

Please, assure that the following stuff is correctly setup in your project:

- use `SplitCompatApplication` as your `Application` class;
- call `SplitCompat.installActivity(this)` on `Activities` that use a dynamic feature;

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)

    SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
}
```

---

For more info, please do a thoughtful reading of the following codelab:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/

Comment: I also think it helps to publish in the Internal test track or Alpha/Beta to get rid of this error. Maybe others can confirm.